# "is being on something"

Tags: stative-verbs, progressive-aspect

The second sentence causes me problems. I have seen it somewhere. For me it looks like the verb **to be** is used twice (is / being). Is it grammatically correct? If yes, what does the second usage give to the meaning?

> 1) The toaster **is** on the stand.
>
> 2) The toaster **is being** on the stand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbs like *be*, *know*, *have*, *love*, *believe*, *want* and many others which express a *state* are not in their ordinary senses cast in the progressive. Some may be cast in the progressive with  different meanings ...

> John is being a jerk = *John is behaving like a jerk*, not *John is a jerk*.
>   Anne is having a baby = *Anne is giving birth*, not *Anne possesses a baby*.
>   I'm loving it! = *I am enjoying it immensely!* not *I love it!*

But a toaster is incapable of behaviour, so  your second sentence is ungrammatical.

Grammatically, a *state* is one type of *aspect*, which you may read about [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).