# Use of "I'm loving"

Tags: tense, present-continuous, aspect, stative-verbs

The couple screenshots are taken from *Riddick 2013*:

[image]
[image]

The two characters use "I'm loving", which I think is very informal. Does the present progressive tense convey any subtle nuances which the simple present tense would not?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13306/230

Comment: I read that before, but I still think it's somewhat different. :) @snailboat

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right.  The non-stative *love* here is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

Some state verbs such as love, like, and enjoy can be used for talking about a state that's for a short period of time. Look at the following sentences:

I love parties. (The present simple indicates a permanent state).

I am loving this party. (The present continuous indicates  the state that's for a short period of time/temporary).

Comment: Yeah, this I know, but why would the speakers emphasize the temporariness? Does it imply they could change their mind in a while? This is a pragmatical issue, not a grammatical one.

Comment: Kinzle B,  I have answered your question in terms of grammar. I am sorry I   can't answer your comments.